# Why use lists for navigation?

Tags: html, css

Since I've started learning css and html (now bear in mind that has only been a few weeks) I've been using inline-block anchors for my navigation menus, no lists. Just a div with anchor tags in. Reason being the first example I saw used said method and I've not had reason yet to journey from it.

Now pretty much all guides I've seen use lists, in tandem with inline/inline-blocks.

Now basically, I'd like to ask: why lists? It just seems like extra mark-up to me.

That's it really! Just, why?

Thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: always try to use those elements that describe best what you want to express. A menu typically is a list of entries. So use a list.

The fact that you can mimic such a list using other elements is not wrong. But it does not change a thing. A list is a list and should be written as a list. It is more intuitive and easier to understand for others. Also for you yourself when you come back to your code much later.

The same principle applies in other situation. An example: why not use tables for layout purposes? It has been done for at least two decades of web programming and works pretty well. Some people still do it. But layout typically does not deal with tables. It typically deals with a 2 dimensional layout, where elements are positioned absolute or relative to each other. So the clean solution is to do exactly that. Using markup, positioning, floats, cleans, containers and the like. Do not miss use things when you can implement a clean solution.

Comment: Thank-you very much for such a helpful explanation! I've been under the thought that less is better (plus the default stylings of lists always knock me for a loop). But I see that is a rather bad practice. 

Another query if I may. I've been using inline-blocks for layout too, rather than floating. Mainly as I do not like the look of the overflow hack of the extra mark-up required for clearing. Is that something of an acceptable practice, the use of inline-blocks I mean, for sidebars and other such things?

Comment: Nothing generally speaks against using the style options css and web browsers offer. But an 'inline-block' display rules serves a different purpose than floating. They create different effects (or better behavior) in the layout. So it is more a question of what you want to achieve than of whether it is "an acceptable practice".

Comment: The question is mainly opinion-based; this answer is entirely opinion-based, with no references to tangible technical benefits or disadvantages. And the logic would equally imply that any sentence, being a list of words, should be marked up as a list, etc.