# Why do we use unordered lists to make navs?

Tags: html, css

Why do almost everybody I see use this kind of structure when creating some sort of navigation

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/link1">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link2">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link3">link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

instead of this?

```
<div>
    <a href="/link1">link1</a>
    <a href="/link2">link2</a>
    <a href="/link3">link3</a>
</div>
```

What are the advantages of the first one compared to the last one? Since so many are doing it this way.

Comment: First link in Google https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Comment: In my opinion lists allow for more control over your navigation. Not only that, but semantically it makes sense, since navigation bars are really lists of links to different pages on your site. Using nested lists also works better for creating drop down menus. I have seen people run into issues when using only divs for their navigations.

Comment: Think about screen readers, site crawlers, etc. It's about semantics.

Comment: @mplungjan The link you gave actualöly advocates **not to use lists** for navigation purposes (which I completely disagree with).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use lists for navigation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880503/why-use-lists-for-navigation)

Comment: I posted it for alternative to the rest :)

Comment: @connexo - no it doesn't - the linked post opens a discussion on the subject, and if you read the comments, it's clear that there are real users gaining real benefits from the list markup. That's far more important than abstract notions about semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about **semantic** use of html. You have a list of links, so you use the appropriate html element which in this case is either a `<ul>` (if order doesn't matter *semantically*) or an orderer list `<ol>` (if order is meaningful, for example if you have a month navigation listing January to December).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/semantics

Answer (score 3):

In short, because the content is a list of links, so we write markup that reflects that.

It gives us more options for styling the links (since the additional markup gives us more elements to play with), and it lets us tell them apart without access to visual styling.

[image: Screenshot of Lynx]

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is a actually a list, that's why. It's a game of semantics. But I personally prefer to use  and  navigation (when I'm designing from scratch).